# Can we reduce the size of the XMSS signature?

Tags: signature, post-quantum-cryptography, cryptocurrency

As XMSS is post-quantum we can use it to secure blockchain. One of the main disadvantage of XMSS is its signature size. If we can reduce the size of the signature then we can use XMSS in the blockchain. XMSS signature contains the `Sign on message+ index of OTS + Authentication path`. If we can store the OTS index and Authentication path on off-chain such as a wallet, isn't is significantly reduce the size of the signature?

Comment: From a security point of view you can do this. However, from a functional point of view: These are required to verify the signature. How do other parties verify the signature (like miners...)?